# incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, search, utf-8

Ruby 2.1
sqlite 3

I can write and read data from the database but can not search.
There is a search field in a view, when submit there is

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError in AdvertisementsController
incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
```

but parameters in log are

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "search"=>"essai"}
```

"essai" is the word in the search field.

**view.erb**

```
<%= form_tag advertisements_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

**advertisements_controller.rb**

```
def index
    if params[:search]
      @advertisements = Advertisement.find(:all, :conditions => [' name LIKE ? or content LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%" ])
    else
      @advertisements = @advertisements.published.
        include_associations.page(params[:page])
    end
  end
```

What's wrong ?